# my panel for a share link wont drop down. nothing looks wrong with the code

Tags: javascript, css

My panel for a share link won't drop down. Nothing looks wrong with the code:

```js
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/device.min.js"></script> 
<!--=======================================================================================
    SCRIPT FOR RESPONSIVE TAB
=========================================================================================-->
<!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
<script src="js/marquee.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
        $(function (){
            createMarquee({
            });
        });
        </script>
<script src="script/footmenu.js"></script>       
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 
    // Open in new window
    $("#box").click(function () {
        window.open($(this).find("a:first").attr("href"));
        return false;
    });
 
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#send_sub').click(function() {
    $text = $('#email_sub').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     url: "subscribe_processor.php",
     data: "text="+$text,
     success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
     }
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#send_sub').click(function() {
    $text = $('#email_sub').val();
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     url: "subscribe_processor.php",
     data: "text="+$text,
     success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
     }
    });
   });
  });
 </script>
 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".flip .panel").click(function(){
        $(".panel").show();
         });
        });   
 </script>
```

```css
.share-cont {
 float: right;
 padding-top:0;
}
.share-div {
 padding-top: 10px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
 width: 200px;
}
.share-div a {
 font-size: 16px;
}
.share-div a:hover {
 color: #008740;
}
.print:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f02f";
 padding-right: 8px;
}
.share-link:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f045";
 padding-right: 8px;

}
.print-div {
 float: left;
 width: 60px;
}
.panel, .flip {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: right;
}
.flip {
 width: 80px;
}
.panel {
 background: #FFF; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
 width: 200px;
 display:none;
}
div.flip:hover panel{
 display:block;
 visibility:visible;
}

.panel h3 {
 color: #4C2804;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.panel ul li {
 padding: 5px 0 3px 8px;

}
.fb-share:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f082";
 margin-right: 8px;
 color: #385397;
}
.tw-share:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: '\f081';
 color: #00ACED;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.linked-share:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: '\f08c';
 color: #2175A2;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.plus-share:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: '\f0d4';
 color: #CD3D2C;
 margin-right: 8px;
}
.mail-share:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: '\f0e0';
 margin-right: 8px; 
}
```

```html
  <div class="container well-mini-3">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 share-cont">
          <div class="share-div">
            <div class="print-div"> <a href="javascript:window.print()" class="print">Print</a> </div>
            <div class="flip"> <a href="#" class="share-link" onclick="event.preventDefault();" >Share</a> </div>
            <div class="panel">
              <h3>Share this Page</h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo $pageURL; ?>" target="_blank" class="fb-share">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $pageURL ?>" target="_blank" class="tw-share">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?summary=&ro=false&mini=true&url=<?php echo $pageURL; ?>" target="_blank" class="linked-share">Linked-in</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo $pageURL ?>" target="_blank" class="plus-share">Google Plus</a></li>
                <li><a href="mailto: ?subject=Checkout this webpage&cc= &body=I came across this link and thought it might be helpful.%0A%0A<?php echo $pageName; ?>:%0A<?php echo $pageURL; ?>%0A%0AThanks." class="mail-share">Email</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
   
          </div>
          <!--End of share-div-->
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're targetting an element that has a class "panel" and is a child of an element of class "flip" on the click. But that's probably not what you were trying to target (since that is the hidden panel you're trying to show), which is why it isn't working. Try:

`$(".flip").click(function(){ ...`

Comment: it still doesnt work i thimg there is sumtim conflicting with it. dnt knw.